# Including Graphics in reaction Environment

Tags: macros, environments, includegraphics, chemistry, chemmacros

I want to include **graphics** from chemdraw etc. (i.e. *.eps*) within a reaction env of the **chemmacros** package. With this i I hope to achive usage of the same counter, labeling etc. used in the reaction enviroment.

I have tried using:

```
\NewChemReaction{reactionfig}{scheme}
```

Sadly this did not include it  in the list of reactions nor did it add the counter to the figure.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you tried. Also, do you get any error messages from your code? I would expect `\NewChemReaction{reactionfig}{scheme}` resulting in errors.

Comment: I'd rather go the other way around and add reactions to the list of schemes

Comment: @leandriis Thank you kindly.
Neither the definition as **scheme** nor as figure has issued any errors. 
  'Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active'

Comment: @cgnieder I've also thought about doing that but i do not know how to alter already existing counter. Do you have any idea how that would look like  ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hacky solution that does what I think you want to achieve (it requires to change the layout of the list of reactions but that must not be a bad thing, IMHO.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{chemmacros,caption,newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lor,placement=h,name=Reaction]{reactionfig}

\chemsetup{
  modules = reactions ,
  reactions/list-entry = \hack
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \hack #1#2#3 \tl_use:N #4
  { \protect \numberline {\thereaction} {\ignorespaces#4\relax} }

\cs_set_protected:Npn \chemmacros_add_reaction_description:n #1
  { \tl_gset:Nn \g__chemmacros_reaction_description_tl {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\let\c@reactionfig\c@reaction
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofreactions

\begin{reaction}[reaction one]
  CH4 + 2 O2 -> 2 H2O + CO2
\end{reaction}

\begin{reactionfig}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{somefigure}
  \caption{reactionfig one}
\end{reactionfig}

\end{document}
```

[image]